# GIMP: How to hide top bar that shows opened images?

Tags: gimp

How to hide top bar that shows the tabs of opened images? I'm including a screenshot to show the navigation bar.

[image]

It's wasting some of my screen area, so I want to hide it. How is it possible to do this? The same bar I can dock to my right toolbox menu (take a look at the screenshot).

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?  The thumbnail is so huge and ugly and I would prefer just to have a small tab with the filename, or just the ability to hide it (keeping my docks)

Answer (score 3):

Gimp now¹ has this ability: in the *Windows* menu, there is now a checkbox which reads “Show Tabs”.

<sub>¹ The feature [has been added](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/merge_requests/39) in October 2018, so I guess it should be available from version 2.10.8 of Gimp.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

It is togable by pressing the `tab` key - that is intened to temporarily toggle the application into "paint mode" - as it hides the requested app bar, along with all palettes and dockable dialogs. It maximizes the painting area though.

Pressing `tab` again will show all dialogs, and the tab dialog back. Unlike other elements like rulers, scrollbars and top menu, the tab bar can not be hidden in a per-image way, and switching to the "no controls visible" mode by `tab` is the only way to do it.

Or, you could try working in the classic "multiple window" mode - in which all GIMP windows - including all dialogs - are separate System level windows. That way, each open image has its own top level window, and one can maximize space. It may be hard to reach a suitable arrangement, but it can be more producive than the Single Window move if tunned correctly. I like to use a virtual desktop to contain all GIMP Windows (almost a must for this mode), and switch my Window Manager to "focus follow mouse" mode, with a 300ms delay to raise windows. On the various Linux desktops those are configurable options. For Windows there might be something out there - [How do you enable focus follows mouse in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/954021/how-do-you-enable-focus-follows-mouse-in-windows-10) -http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-use-multiple-desktops-in-windows-10/

Comment: This removes all of the toolbars and not just the one at the top.

Comment: I accidently pressed `tab` key and spent last two hours searching how to find tabs again.  The only way is to press `tab`, no option whatsoever works.  This should be definitely made better.