# scroll down the browser while working in another monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, external-display

I'm on windows 10, I have dual screens. In a window I read the docs, in the other I write code. Is it possible to scoll the docs while still being in the editor monitor?

I don't want to keep switching everytime I need to scroll

Comment: Do you want to keep the mouse pointer over your editor?  Leaving the pointer over the docs browser lets me scroll them with the mouse wheel while the editor maintains keyboard focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Scroll another window without losing focus

You have at least two options:

### 1) Focus-follows-mouse

*(aka focus-follows-pointer)*

This lets you scroll a window without having it in focus. There are a number of options for this [in Windows 10 as laid out in this QA](https://superuser.com/questions/954021/how-do-you-enable-focus-follows-mouse-in-windows-10):

- [x-Mouse Controls](http://joelpurra.com/Projects/X-Mouse_Controls/), an open source utility (credit to [ArthurChanez](https://superuser.com/a/1076587))
- there is also a PowerShell option, as per [golvok](https://superuser.com/a/1209478):

  ```
  $signature = @"
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, ref 
  int lpvParam, int flags );
  "@

  $systemParamInfo = Add-Type -memberDefinition  $signature -Name SloppyFocusMouse -passThru

  [Int32]$newVal = 1
  $systemParamInfo::SystemParametersInfo(0x1001, 0, [REF]$newVal, 2)
  ```

### 2) A custom hotkey to scroll another window

This is doable with a hotkey-automation-type software like [autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/)

> AutoHotkey is a free, open-source scripting language for Windows that allows users to easily create small to complex scripts for all kinds of tasks such as: form fillers, auto-clicking, macros, etc.

With autohotkey you can capture (global/window-specific) hotkeys and send them to a specific / another window.

The benefits of this approach are:

- keep your hands on the keyboard!
- you could have a number of different hotkeys to scroll by different amounts (5 lines, half page, page, etc)
- hotkeys to quickly jump to other documentation sections, or other tasks that might steal focus with the mouse
- you could make the hotkeys specific to your code IDE (rather than global), so that they only scroll the documentation window in that context you don't have to learn a new mouse behaviour
- learning autohotkey automation may be beneficial in other areas

Comment: My understanding is that scrolling was no longer tied to cursor focus though natively in W10.