# Possible for Powershell script to disable the accessibility shortcuts in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, accessibility

Holding shift on a new Windows installation prompts use of Filter Keys.

I want to run a PS script to disable this.

Comment: What have you tried?  We generally don't write scripts.  We will help fix them.

Comment: You might start here: https://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/StickyKeys-Turning-off-accessibility-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: If you want something quick & easy and don't mind logoff/logon for changes to take effect, you can script a modification of the registry keys mention in the link posted by uSlacker. If you want to learn something that could serve you well in the future, you could modify the code posted by Matthijs in answer to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/954021/how-do-you-enable-focus-follows-mouse-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been added as a feature to an extensive suite of Windows Scripts to configure Windows 10. The feature is called `DisableAccessibilityKeys`

https://github.com/Disassembler0/Win10-Initial-Setup-Script

The specific code:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Accessibility\StickyKeys" -Name "Flags" -Type String -Value "506"
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Accessibility\ToggleKeys" -Name "Flags" -Type String -Value "58"
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Response" -Name "Flags" -Type String -Value "122"
```

Comment: Does not work for me, Win 10 Version 10.0.19041 Build 19041 ...