# How can I make the mouse cursor always active on an application but the keyboard is active on another application

Tags: windows, powershell, keyboard, mouse

I need to achieve focus follows mouse but keyboard focus doesn't follow mouse. So the focus is active where my mouse is staying, but the keyboard is safely typing in the other window without changing focus from the window where the mouse is pointing.

I tried this powershell script from here [link](https://superuser.com/a/1209478/1790294):

```
$signature = @"
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, ref 
int lpvParam, int flags );
"@

$systemParamInfo = Add-Type -memberDefinition  $signature -Name SloppyFocusMouse -passThru

[Int32]$newVal = 1
$systemParamInfo::SystemParametersInfo(0x1001, 0, [REF]$newVal, 2)
```

but it only make the mouse active on the first application but as soon as I type with keyboard on the other application it loses focus.

Comment: Explain why you want what you want. Focus on the goal, not how you think the problem should be solved. That powershell script has a different purpose.

Comment: edited @Gantendo

Comment: But I still don't understand *why* you want to do that. What is the goal? How would this help you?

Comment: This is not a PowerShell code issue, or any programming language really. That in not how UI works. You certainly can have one to many things running at the same time, you can not have UI focus on multiple items at the same time. Mouse focus in `onenter`, `move`, and `onleave` for a GUI. Keyboard focus is `tab order` on a GUI.  Those are two entirely two different physical things. Human interaction with a system/system object/graphical objects is a don't to one thing. Mechanical actions are singular things. Each of these things has its separate own system bus communication.