# Windows 11 Mouse in and out of dialogue box

Tags: windows, windows-11

I thought this was a problem\error and would eventually be fixed.  Since windows 11 came out, if you click a dialogue box to activate it and move your mouse out of the dialogue box, it deactivates the dialogue box.  Is there a way I can stop this behaviour?

Comment: 1/2 Do you have any accessibility options or 3rd party Mouse utilities running? The default mode in Windows is not for focus to follow the mouse pointer, but there are utilities that give that function for those who want it. Does this happen in a specific application, or with any dialog presented by any application? Does this happen after you've interacted with (clicked into, typed into, etc) the dialog? In my experience dialogs will often flash when they're opened to get attention, but will not take focus, and I could see that moving your mouse over and then past the dialog might appear

Comment: 2/2 as though focus is following. For further reading, to help you understand some of the functions, and if it doesn't solve your question, to help you give more information that can help us understand your issue better, I recommend reading through this question and its comments and answers: https://superuser.com/questions/954021/how-do-you-enable-focus-follows-mouse-in-windows-10

Comment: @music2myear not that I know of.  It happens when I click into a dialogue box.  When I release my mouse to go type something in, if I happen to move the cursor when transferring my hand to the keyboard, if the cursor goes out of the dialogue box, it deselects and any typing I do is for naught.

Comment: Does focus move between regular windows too, or is it only moving out of dialogs?